# Print out a Drupal Commerce field only if it has a value

Tags: theming, commerce

In Drupal Commerce, you can use the following to print out a field in your node.tpl.php file:

```
<?php print render($content['product:field_NAME']); ?>
```

[See here fore more information](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/node/337#comment-846)

But how do you print a field only if it has content?

For a normal Drupal field you would use the following:

```
<?php if (isset ($node->field_NAME)): ?>
  <?php print $node->field_NAME['und'][0]['safe_value'];?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But that doesn't work with a Drupal commerce field.

I would appreciate if someone could offer any pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content for the referenced product fields is incorporated into the product display(node) using field_extra_fields and normally contents go into the #markup key.

You can use [template_preprocess_node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) and use something like this:

```
if (!isset($variables['content']['product:field_NAME']['#markup'])) {
  unset($variables['content']['product:field_NAME']);
}
```

You could also try [Field formatter conditions](https://drupal.org/project/ffc) module.