# How can I hide and print a field in my tpl.php?

Tags: theming, commerce

I'm using kickstart 2. I have product variation types and a content type for each product. field_desc under the content type manage fields, I have managed to hide and print render successfully in my node--product--type.tpl.php.

However, I have another field called field_spec which is a variation type field rather than a content type field. when I use the following codes in my tpl.php to hide and print the field_spec, this field is not hidden or printed where I want.

I use the following codes to hide and print both field_spec and field_desc however field_spec isn't hiding whereas field_desc is:

```
  <?php
    hide($content['field_desc']);
  ?>

 <?php
 print render($content['field_desc']);
 ?>
```

I have checked that field_spec is spelled correctly, I have cleared caches etc. however I cannot hide and print field_spec.

Is this something to do with the fact field_desc is a content type field whereas field_spec is a variation type field?

Thank you

Comment: what is actually in `$content['field_spec']`?  it *should* be a render array if `hide()` is going to work its magic and put a `['#printed'] = TRUE` in there.

Comment: Are you sure that the variable `$content['field_spec']` is defined in your `node--product--type.tpl.php` file? Since you mentioned that it is not a content field, there is a good chance that it is not defined there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `$content['product:field_NAME']` for this

See this answer for more info: [Print out a Drupal Commerce field only if it has a value](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27440/print-out-a-drupal-commerce-field-only-if-it-has-a-value/89478#89478)

Comment: Great thank you, 
<?php print render($content['product:field_NAME']); ?> works perfectly